# Minimizing Dependency requirements while using abstract generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dependencies

In my Data Access Layer, which is it it's own library, I have a POCO class that represents Database Tables for my Domain Objects.  We can use one as an example, let's call it `MyClassDTO`, even though there are dozens of objects just like it.

In my Business Logic layer, which is in it's own library as well (And references the DAL library)  it has the actual Domain Object class for each object.  Let's use `MyClass`.

The BLL exposes as its API a bunch of Classes like `MyClassBll`, which can be instantiated within a Presentation project in order to gain access to the Domain logic and data.

To make my life easier, most of the BLL objects like `MyClassBll` inherit from a generic abstract `Bll<TModel,TDto>` class.  So, for example `MyClassBll` is declared like so:

```
Public Class MyClassBll : Bll<MyClass,MyClassDto>
```

The Idea here is that the Job of the BLL to take Domain objects, which is the language that the Presentation Layer will be speaking, turn them into DTO's, which is the language that the DAL will be speaking, and vice versa.

It has really made creating the various objects a breeze, expecially since I can override the generic implementation when need be, and just leave it alone when it is straightforward.  So far, so good.

I only hit a problem when I started to use it in my Presentation.  I included the BLL library as a reference, but it won't let me use any methods of `MyClassBLL,` because It doesn't know the definition of `MyClassDto`, which is in the Metadata for `MyClassBll` as it's definition.

I don't WANT my presentation Layer to have to know about my DAL Classes.  How can I satisfy the Compiler?  Is there a way that I can further hide my DAL from the Presentation layer, while still keeping the flexibility of my current design?

for reference, my generic BLL class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Bll<TModel, TDto> : IBll<TModel, TDto>
    where TModel : class
    where TDto : class
{
    protected User User;

    protected static string[] AdminGroups;

    protected bool IsAdmin;

    protected static Func<UnitOfWork, GenericRepository<TDto>> Repository;

    private void AdminCheck()
    {
        if (!IsAdmin)
        {
            throw new SecurityException("That Action Requires Admin Privileges");
        }
    }

    public Bll(User user)
    {
        StaticMapBulder.initialize();
        if (User == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("User Can not be null");
        }
        user = User;
        IsAdmin = false;
        foreach (var AdminGroup in AdminGroups)
        {
            if (user.IsInGroup(AdminGroup))
                {
                    IsAdmin = true;
                }
        }
    }

    public virtual TModel Insert(TModel ItemToAdd)
    {
        AdminCheck();
        using (var uow = new  UnitOfWork())
        {
            var OutgoingDto = MapModelToDto(ItemToAdd);
            var InboundDto = Repository(uow).Insert(OutgoingDto);
            uow.Save();
            return MapDtoToModel(InboundDto);

        }

    }

    public virtual List<TModel> GetAll()
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var InboundDto = Repository(uow).Get();
            var ModelList = new List<TModel>();
            foreach (var item in InboundDto)
            {
                ModelList.Add(MapDtoToModel(item));
            }
            return ModelList;
        }

    }

    public virtual TModel GetByID(int ID)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var InboundDto = Repository(uow).GetByID(ID);
            return MapDtoToModel(InboundDto);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(TModel ItemToUpdate)
    {
        AdminCheck();
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var OutboundDto = MapModelToDto(ItemToUpdate);
            Repository(uow).Update(OutboundDto);
            uow.Save();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TModel ItemToDelete)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var OutboundDto = MapModelToDto(ItemToDelete);
            Repository(uow).Delete(OutboundDto);
            uow.Save();
        }
    }

    public virtual void DeleteByID(int ID)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            Repository(uow).Delete(ID);
            uow.Save();
        }
    }


    virtual public TModel MapDtoToModel(TDto Dto)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TModel>(Dto);
    }

    virtual public TDto MapModelToDto(TModel Model)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TDto>(Model);
    }
}
```

}

Which makes a generic Implementation of that Class look like this:

```
public class MyClassBll : Bll<MyClass, MyClassDto>
{
    public MyClassBll(User user)
        : base(user)
    {

    }

    new protected static Func<UnitOfWork, GenericRepository<MyClassDto>> Repository = x => x.MyClassRepository;
    new protected static string[] AdminGroups = { "MyClassAdministrators" };
}
```

Comment: I think you are over-designing this. What is your application? Keep it simple.

Comment: That's just it, it is for lots of applications.  One application is a Web-socket Server that administers business applications to an internal website.  Another one is a Service that keeps parts of our internal database synchronized with an external, 3rd party database via an API.  The BLL even get's used in a couple Office Add-ins, WPF applications, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't WANT my presentation Layer to have to know about my DAL
>   Classes. How can I satisfy the Compiler? Is there a way that I can
>   further hide my DAL from the Presentation layer, while still keeping
>   the flexibility of my current design?

It's not the compiler you need to satisfy, it's your design requirement.

Why don't you want presentation to know about DTOs? The responsibility of DTOs is to get passed between components. It's perfectly acceptable to use DTOs to pass data from your business classes to your presentation.

You're correct in that you want to hide your DAL from your presentation. You need to change your design to enable this.

I recommend a repository that depends on your DAL. This repository is the only component to depend on your DAL. Now, your business classes can call CRUD operations on your repository. Your business classes perform some transformation and calculation on the data your repository returns. If you need to update your presentation you send it models or DTOs of your now transformed data. Concerns are separated.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  In fact, I realized after working on this project that I might have messed up on my naming conventions.  However, having said that, in the context of my application, the DTO classes have the sole responsability of getting data from the DAL to the BLL.  The BLL then turns everything into the Domain Models that all of the applications are looking for (`Employee`, `Customer`, `Product`, etc.).  I would prefer to make those the only objects that are exposed to consuming applications, and leave the "DTO's" To be handled solely by the BLL.

Comment: I admit that it isn't a big deal.  Currently, the Dto Classes are defined in the DAL.  I could just refactor those into their own class library and expose that to the presentation applications.  I just feel like I should have to, since the applications aren't actually using those classes.

Comment: What ORM are you using? You ideally want your entities or classes that your ORM generates and only one other kind of model that represents the transformed data. Also, your use of generics is not really solving any problem.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework.  `MyClassDto` is an entity that results from it.  it transforms only once, which happens in the BLL.  is there a better palce for that transformation to take place?

Comment: My design would not use `Bll<MyClass,MyClassDto>`. Your abstract bll class looks more like a repository. You should refactor it into a mapper which is what it looks like.

Comment: I like that Idea of Refracting the mapping responsibility into it's own object.  Better separation of concerns.  That should fix my problem.